# Make text field empty everytime a new value will be entered?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

My code currently is a random number generator that allows the users to enter their name and a number to guess and will display their name, their guess and whether that guess is right or not. What it currently does is make it so that it will display each guess whereas I only want it to display the most recent one, how would I go about this? My code is as follows:

```
    public void addClick(View v){

    String randtext ="";
    Random rand = new Random();
    int noofguess = 0;
    int n = rand.nextInt(20)+1; //generate random number
    comments = "";

    comments = tvCommentOuput.getText().toString();
    comments = comments+ "\n" + etCommentInput.getText();
    comments = comments+ "\n" + etnameInput.getText();


    int userguess =     Integer.parseInt(etCommentInput.getText().toString());
    if (userguess < 1 || userguess > 20){
        comments = comments+ "\n" + "Please enter a number between 1-20!";
        tvCommentOuput.setText(comments);
    }
    else if (userguess == n){
        comments = comments+ "\n" + "You got it right!";
        tvCommentOuput.setText(comments);


    } else if (userguess > n) {
        comments = comments+ "\n" + "Number too high!";
        tvCommentOuput.setText(comments);

        noofguess = noofguess + 1;
    } else{
        comments = comments+ "\n" + "Number too low!";
        tvCommentOuput.setText(comments);


        noofguess = noofguess + 1;
    } 




    randtext = Integer.toString(n);








}
```

Comment: comment  `comments = tvCommentOuput.getText().toString();` and run it again

Comment: Why are you still using eclipse ? o.O

Comment: @Juni lol what does that matter with the question?

Comment: @Fondesa lol don't know,may be curiosity :-P